# Continuity of $ f(x,y) = \frac{|x|^a|y|^b}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} $ at the point (0,0) using $\epsilon, \alpha$ definition.

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $a > 0$ and $b > 0$.
>
> We consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as:
>
> $$ f(x,y) = \frac{|x|^a|y|^b}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \text{ if } (x,y) \neq (0,0); 
> \text{ } f(0,0) = 0$$
>
> 1. Prove in terms of $\epsilon, \alpha$ that if $a + b > 1$, then $f$ is continuous.
> 2. What happens when $a + b < 1$ ?

---

$f$ is continuous at the point $(0,0)$ by definition means:

$$||(x,y)||_2 < \alpha \implies |f(x,y)| < \epsilon$$

When dealing with single variable functions, we start from $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon $ and go backwards to get the $\alpha$ that would satisfy:

$$ |x - x_0| < \alpha \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon $$.

In our case of 2 variables, for a fixed $\epsilon$, we have:

$$ |f(x,y)| = \frac{|x|^a|y|^b}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} < \epsilon $$

$$ \implies \frac{|x|^a|y|^b}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} < \epsilon $$

$$ \implies \frac{|x|^a|y|^b}{||(x,y)||_2} < \epsilon $$

$$ \implies \frac{ |x|^a|y|^b }{ \epsilon } < ||(x,y)||_2  $$

I cannot get $ \alpha $ from the above inequality.

I don't see how to proceed to get: $a + b > 1 $ implies $f$ is continuous in terms of $\epsilon, \alpha$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want $\frac{1}{\epsilon} < \frac{||(x,y)||_2}{|x|^a|y|^b}$. Since $|x|,|y| \leq ||(x,y)||_2$, it suffices to make sure that $\frac{1}{\epsilon} < \frac{||(x,y)||_2}{||(x,y)||_2^{a+b}}$. This is equivalent to $||(x,y)||_2^{a+b-1} < \epsilon$, or $||(x,y)||_2 < \epsilon^{1/(a+b-1)}$. Hence, we can take $\alpha = \epsilon^{1/(a+b-1)}$.

If $a+b <1$, then $\lim_{r \to 0} f(r,r) = +\infty$, so surely, $f$ is not continuous.

If $a+b=1$, then $\lim_{r \to 0} f(r,r) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, so surely, $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome. Thank you for the question. I enjoy these things.